# Export blender mesh with backed modifier animation

Tags: animation, unity

I've created a sphere to rectangle deformation using a **Cast** modifier.

I have also animated the **Factor** properties to show in 40 frames that transformation.

Now I want to export in Unity the results with that backed animations.

However when I apply the modifier the animation is lost (also in Blender).

[image]

How can I preserve the animation?

Thanks.

Comment: what you can try to do is export it to an alembic file and import that. Does that help? i tried it to export and import it with Blender and that worked for me. But i don't know whether unity supports alembic....

Comment: @Chris, Unity supports alembic but this solution is not supported on every platform. Is there a way into Blender to preserve anim?

Comment: i don't know another way....